# Simple local restful web service

Tags: web-services, rest

I've created a very basic iOS/Android application. The next step is to make the app load some data from a server. For now, all I need is to get an XML from which I'll be loading the data from a local server which will have a couple of simple functions. Which is the fastest approach to achieve this goal? I'm on a Mac machine, and I don't care about the language, although I had Java or Python in mind.

Comment: Why not serving static JSON files, if only needed for test purposes?

Comment: Because I need a function, something really simple. Probably just being able to retrieve two versions of an xml file according to a single parameter would be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend the use of Jersey. This Java framework is light, easy to work with and is the JAX-RS reference implementation. It produces XML and JSON out of the box. [Its documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/index.html) is a good place to start.

What you need:

- a Java Project
- a web.xml

> ```
> <web-app>
>   <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
>       </servlet-class>
>   </servlet>
>   <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
>   </servlet-mapping>
> </web-app>
> ```

- some dependencies (jersey-core and jersey-server), using maven, editing the pom.xml is enough

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
>   <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
>   <version>1.7</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

- a resource

> ```
> @Path("/product")
> public class ProductResource {
>
>   @GET
>   public Response getCallbackUrl() {
>     Product product = new Product("bike");
>     return Response.ok(product).build();
>   }
> }
> ```

- a server. If you never use a Java server, using Jetty-Embedded is the simpler:

> ```
> package com.xebia.server;
>
> import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
> import org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
>
> public class EmbeddedServer {
>
>   static Server server;
>   static int port = 8080;
>
>   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
>       server = new Server(port);
>       server.addHandler(new WebAppContext("src/main/webapp", "/"));
>       server.start();
>   }
> }
> ```

And you're done

Comment: The fact is that we just need a quick tutorial to get a simple web service running for testing purposes only, we just need 2 functions which return 2 different and simple XMLS, that documentation seems huge!

Comment: A lot to see, yes, but very easy to start with. An hour or two is enough for what you're trying to do, starting from scratch. Answer updated.

Comment: Do you know a Java IDE (eclipse)? Do you know maven? I need to know from where to start.

Comment: [Here is a working sample](https://github.com/yamsellem/Backbone-Jersey). Download it, import it in Eclipse, and Run it. In your browser look at localhost:8080/resource/product.

Comment: I know Eclipse, I don't know maven. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.